# Is there a faster way to scan SCSI ports different from 'sbin/rescan-scsi-bus'?

Tags: 16.04, command-line, ssd, portscan, scsi

I'm currently developing a program that fetches and validates the information inside 5 SSDs at the same time. My problem is the command I'm using to scan the drives (`/sbin/rescan-scsi-bus`) takes too long and sometimes freezes my program or the entire computer. So what I'm looking for is a way to scan the SSDs even if I need to change some environment variables or so. I'm using a test board to perform this scan and I've tried other commands like the following:

```
echo 1 > /sys/block/sdX **with** echo "- - -" | tee /sys/class/scsi_host/host?/scan
/sbin/rescan-scsi-bus --luns=0 --ids=0 --channels=0
/sbin/rescan-scsi-bus       # with other parameters
```

And a bash command to delete all disks except the one that has the OS mounted.

Comment: your formatting in the question appears messed up. Are `echo 1 > /sys/block/sdX` and `echo "- - -" | tee /sys/class/scsi_host/host?/scan` supposed to be two separate commands ?

Comment: Yes, they are two separate commands, but I ran both commands on the program, I tried first deleting every disk connected to the SCSI port with `echo 1 > /sys/block/sdX` and then scanning all of them with the  `echo "- - -" | tee /sys/class/scsi_host/host?/scan` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came with a solution to my problem.

Even it's an old kernel command it helped me to resolve wait times and to assure all SSDs are scanned before the validation.

```
echo 'scsi add-single-device X 0 0 0' > /proc/scsi/scsi
```

and

```
echo 'scsi remove-single-device X 0 0 0' > /proc/scsi/scsi
```

where X is the number of the host I want to mount/unmount, in this specific case, for example for 'ATA1' port host is 0, so it would be:

```
echo 'scsi add-single-device 0 0 0 0' > /proc/scsi/scsi
```

and

```
echo 'scsi remove-single-device 0 0 0 0' > /proc/scsi/scsi
```